# How can send Flash (Notification) SMS by Android?

Tags: java, android, message

I want send the sms as flash(notification) sms by this,that message should be displayed immediately on recipient mobile screen but not stored.

please tell me how can i do this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: direct flash sms not possible in android like nokia mobile u use Statusbar Notification

Comment: FlashSMS.apk this an application which actuality does what i said

Comment: @imrankhan: Android can show the flash messages (tested on HTC Explorer).

Comment: i have tested this FlashSMS.apk on LG optimus but not sowing any message.@Mudassir if u have code then answer this post

Comment: @K.Muthu: This feature doesn't seems available through official APIs. You can use reflection to do so. But use at you own risk. Here is a reference; http://virtualabs.fr/ndh2k11/hacking-android.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Wap Push over SMS is an SMS message with special encoding. The content of the message has to be encoded special XML form.

For more details google wap push over sms.